# Positioning text inputs?

Tags: html, css, forms

I haven't used forms alot so Im not sure whats going on here.
Im trying to position a text input inline with a button but it doesnt seem to work. You can see what Im doing here:
http://jsfiddle.net/gagalug/BEBAH/

Thanks.

Comment: While JSFiddle is useful for providing working examples, please provide a complete question on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Quentin Just seemed like to much to write for a simple thing. Will do next time. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to your style:

```
img, input[type=image] {vertical-align: bottom;}
```

This will prevent baseline issues on images and image-inputs. Solves your problem instantly.

You know, more people really should know about this. Even the guy who writes a site as big as QuirksMode is ignorant of this fact.

Comment: Hmm this method seems much better but I will align it in the middle as it suits my needs better. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
input { vertical-align: middle; }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways.

1. Positioning relative to the parent div and position absolute to the child.
2. vertical-align: middle; for both input

Answer (score 0):

Hey i think you want this

option you just define your  **vertical-align:top;**

```
#text{
    height: 40px;
    vertical-align: top;

}
```

live demo http://jsfiddle.net/BEBAH/4/

Comment: Hey thanks so much. Also just wondering do you know why it does that? haha Thanks.

Comment: Bad idea. It's unnecessary, and relies on too much.

Comment: Absolute positioning is a rather brute force tool, and really not needed to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your CSS as below.

```
div{
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 500px;
        height: 50px;
        float:left;
    }
    #text{
        height: 40px;
        top: 0px;
        float:left;
    }
```